# ¿Como pasar variables a una consulta sql?

Tags: sql, php7, login, php5

Primero creo un objeto Login:

```
$login=new Login($usuario,$contra);
```

Después de crear el objeto llamo a la función;

```
$respuesta=$login->Loguearse();
```

y la función hace una consulta a la base de datos y me devuelve un *array* con el resultado

```
public function Loguearse(){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $con = $conexion->abrirConexion();

    $sql= "select * from personal where email=".$this->getEmail()." and password=".$this->getContra();
    echo $sql;
```

Este `echo` me imprime bien lo que contiene las variables, es decir que las variables sí me imprimen los valores del objeto.

```
select * from personal where email=ejemplo@ejemplo.com and password=1234
```

Y aquí hago la consulta:

```
 try {
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $resultado;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error conectando con la base de datos: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

El código funciona si hago la SQL de esta forma:

```
select * from email=ejemplo@ejemplo.com and password=1234;
```

pero pasando los parámetros ésta no me devuelve nada.

Comment: Hola, al enviar la consulta debes colocar el email y el password entre comillas `$sql= "select * from personal where email='".$this->getEmail()."' and password='".$this->getContra()."'";`

Comment: Si funciona muchas graacias!